# Using Quick Install in Visual Studio doesn't actually add the packages to your project

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, npm-install, bower-install

Hello I'm trying to use the Visual Studio extension Quick Install Package to install packages via bower and npm. One example is angular-loading-spinner

When I give the command using the interface, I see that the package.json file is updated and or the bower.json file is updated with the package dependency, but I'm still unable to actually reference the packages as instructed in my html using the  tags. No actual files are added to the project, so I feel like I'm really missing something here, or simply don't understand what this package installer is actually meant to do. There doesn't seem to be any clear tutorial on this I can find online, or any good information. It just all assumes it works fine. Can anyone please advise? Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCNcT.png)

Comment: It will always dump the files into the node_modules folder

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome my friend! Don't forget to mark as resolved my answers. Keep rocking!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike, I'm glad to know that my answer was the correct. For future users that have the same concern, they need to look at the folder `node_modules` to find out all the libraries installed.

Comment: I can't find Quick Install Package and I can't find Node_modules folder.  Any idea where these are supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

This was put in the node_modules folder as pointed out by Jonathan Brizio. The issue was that the files were hidden and had to be included in the project.